# Zend's framework .htaccess VS password protected .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, password-protection

We use zend framework for all websites hosted in our server, and I'm facing a situation here where I am not seeing any way out of it and a way to make it work.

My server uses CentOS + php 5.3 + WHM/cPanel.

One of the websites must have a password protected folder:  `http://website.com/files/protected_files`

But as you guys know, Zend's .htaccess that is currently located in `/home/website/public_html` is not letting `/home/website/public_html/files/protected_files/.htaccess` work properly.

If I disable Zend's `.htaccess` the URL prompts for password and when I type I can see my files, but when I enable Zend's `.htaccess` it will see that URL as a true URL and will throw up an error that the page cannot be found.

Here is my Zend's .htaccess:

```
Rewriteengine on 
RewriteRule !\.(js|txt|ico|gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG|css|swf|pdf|xml|XML|eot|svg|ttf|woff)$ index.php
```

And this is the .htaccess located in the protected_files

```
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "protected" 
AuthUserFile "/home/website/.htpasswds/public_html/files/protected_files/passwd" 
require valid-user
```

What am I missing here. Why is it not working?

I did tried enabling `Allowoverride AuthConfig` / `AllowOverride none` / `AllowOverride all` but all of this did not work. 
I also tried to put the `.htacces`s content from protected_files inside `httpd.conf` but it did not work.

I have root access to the server, so any tip will help!

Answer (score 0):

See ZF2's Skeleton Application `.htaccess`:

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/public/.htaccess

As you can see from this configuration it will only rewrite the request to `index.php` if the file does not exist. This is in contrast to the current rule you have configured which is rewrite anything if it does not have one of the extensions you have specified.

Comment: So you are saying that I should use the same .htaccess that it is on this link? I use a content manager at website.com/manager.

Comment: Yes, replace your current Zend `.htaccess` with the one I linked, it will prevent Apache rewriting requests if the file you request exists. I'm not sure what you mean by you use a content manager.

Comment: I just added the same content that it is on this link, and the .htaccess telling to protect the directory will just not work. It shows: "The page cannot be found" instead of prompting for password.

Comment: By the way I'm using ZF1 not 2. And when I meant content manager, it is a interface like Wordpress where the client will login to put content. If i leave the .htaccess rule the way it is on the link, when I try to access website.com/manager it will just show the files listed instead of prompting to type username and password for the customer put his content.

Comment: You have ZF2 tagged in your question, not ZF1. Also I just tested using the `.htaccess` I linked in conjunction  with a folder that is password protected and it successfully prompted me for a password rather than rewriting to index.php. You must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: I wrongly type the wrong zend version on tag, sorry. I'm completly new here, and I don't know how to change it now. If I remove the .htaccess I'm able to see all the files listed, if I put the .htaccess there telling to password protect it shows that the page cannot be found.

Comment: OK, I tried some different stuff. The main .htaccess has the same content that it is on the link. When I access website.com/files it shows a list of files, so far so good. But if I try to access website.com/files/protected_files it says that the page cannot be found. If I remove the .htaccess I can see the protected_files when I access website.com/files, I see there protected_files and I can access and it shows a list of files.